# Does the quran contradicts itself, whom actually are the chosen family/people?

Tags: quran, islamic-basis

Salam
Does the quran contradicts itself concerning thé 4 chosen families ? Because in Surah 3 verse 33 it is said that the fourth chosen family was Imran family while un Surah 19 verse it says that the fourth chosen family is israel

> Indeed, Allah chose Adam and Noah and the family of Abraham and the FAMILY OF IMRAN over the worlds [S3V33](http://legacy.quran.com/3/33)
>
> Those were the ones upon whom Allah bestowed favor from among the prophets of the descendants of Adam and of those We carried [in the ship] with Noah, and of the descendants of Abraham and ISRAEL, ....[S19V58](http://legacy.quran.com/19/58)

Comment: Why should it be contradictory the second verse includes the offspring of Adam, Ibraheem and Ya'qoub (Israel)  and aal 'Imran are among these.

Comment: Yes but in the first verse it says that ONLY Imran family was the chosen (which exclude jacob) while in the second verse it says that Jacob AND his seeds were chosen

Comment: @MuslimAsker, it neither says ONLY in the Arabic text nor in the English translation you linked to. Where did you get the notion of "ONLY" from?

Comment: But why are Israel (Jacob) and his seeds not included in the first verse ?

Comment: Whats the contradiction? Israel was Abraham's grandson and so part of his family. Imran was a descendant of Israel. For an example which deals with Israel separately see [2:47](https://quran.com/2/47)

Answer (score 1):

**Re-reading verse 3:33**

Let's re- read the first of the mentioned verses in more context:

> Indeed, Allah chose **Adam** and **Noah** and **the family of Abraham** and **the family of 'Imran** over the worlds - ([3:33](http://legacy.quran.com/3/33))
>   **Descendants, some of them from others**. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing. ([3:34](http://legacy.quran.com/3/34))

What does this verse say?

It says Allah has chosen Adam, Noah and the family of Abraham (Ibraheem) and the family of 'Imran over all other people and families and adds that they are descendants from each other, so there are family bonds (relationships) between these chosen people. And nowhere in this verse there's a exclusion for other people to have been chosen, as the verse is very open on to whom this may refer, with the exclusion of those clearly named: Adam, Nuh, the family of Ibraheem and the family of 'Imran. In fact the quran for example excluded a son of Nuh from these.

See also in tafsir ibn Kathir:

> Allah states that He has chosen these households over the people of the earth. For instance, Allah chose **Adam**, created him with His Hand and blew life into him. Allah commanded the angels to prostrate before Adam, taught him the names of everything and allowed him to dwell in Paradise, but then sent him down from it out of His wisdom.
>   Allah chose **Nuh** and made him the first Messenger to the people of the earth, when the people worshipped idols and associated others with Allah in worship. Allah avenged the way Nuh was treated, for he kept calling his people day and night, in public and in secret, for a very long time. However, his calling them only made them shun him more, and this is when Nuh supplicated against them. So Allah caused them to drown, and none among them was saved, except those who followed the religion that Allah sent to Nuh.
>   Allah also chose the **household of Ibrahim**, including the master of all mankind, and the Final Prophet, Muhammad, peace be upon him.
>   Allah also chose the **household of 'Imran**, the father of Marym bint 'Imran, the mother of 'Isa, peace be upon them. So 'Isa is from the offspring of Ibrahim, as we will mention in the Tafsir of Surat Al-An`am, Allah willing, and our trust is in Him. (Source [qtafsir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=547&Itemid=46))

according to this one may say that it was not even necessary to mention the family of 'Imran (aal 'Imran) as they are included in the descendants of Ibrahim! So explicitly quoting them just shows their importance and maybe that's why this surah is called surat aal 'Imran!

**Re-reading verse 19:58**

now let's take a look at the second verse in its context, note prior to this verse Allah quoted names of messengers and prophets() among them Ibrahim, Isma'il, Musa and Idriss and their position and rank by HIM before saying:

> Those were the ones upon whom Allah bestowed favor from among the prophets of the **descendants of Adam** and of **those We carried [in the ship] with Noah**, and of **the descendants of Abraham and Israel**, and of those whom We guided and chose. When the verses of the Most Merciful were recited to them, they fell in prostration and weeping. ([19:58](http://legacy.quran.com/19/58))

What does this verse actually say:
As said in my intro this verse came after already quoting Musa, Isma'il, Idriss and Ibraheem () explicitly, which due to the context are among the chosen ones. The verse repeats and extends the list from verse (3:33) by adding the offspring of Adam (Idriss is among them), those whom take refuge in the arch of Nuh (which are believers and -not all- members of his family ), the descendants of Ibraheem (where already mentioned in verse 3:33 and the verses prior to this verse) and there's again a rather unnecessary repetition here which is quoting the descendants of Ya'qoub (Israel) who himself actually is a descendant of Ibraheem. This verse also show no exclusion for others as it states:

> ... and of those whom We guided and chose ...

See also in Tafsir ibn Kathir:

> Allah, the Exalted, says that these Prophets (were favored), but **this does not mean only these Prophets who were mentioned in this Surah**. Rather, it is referring to all of those who were Prophets. Allah merely changes the implication of the discussion from specific individuals to the entire group of Prophets.
>   *(they unto whom Allah bestowed His grace from among the Prophets, of the offspring of Adam.)*
>   As-Suddi and Ibn Jarir both said, "That which is meant by the offspring of Adam is Idris, and what is meant by the offspring of those "whom We carried with Nuh' is Ibrahim, and what is meant by the offspring of Ibrahim is Ishaq, Ya'qub and Isma'il, and what is meant by the offspring of Isra'il is Musa, Harun, Zakariyya, Yayha and 'Isa bin Maryam."
>   Ibn Jarir said, "And that is the distinction of their genealogies, even though Adam gathers all of them (as their original father). This is because among them is he who was not a descendant of those who were on the ship with Nuh, and he that is Idris. For verily, he was the grandfather of Nuh."
>   I say that this is the most apparent meaning, which concludes that Idris is amongst the pillars of Nuh's ancestral lineage. The view that this Ayah refers to the ancestral lineage of the Prophets, is the fact that it is similar to Allah's statement in Surah Al-An'am,
>
> *(And that was our proof which We gave Ibrahim against his people. We raise whom We will in degrees. Certainly your Lord is All-Wise, All-Knowing. And We bestowed upon him Ishaq and Ya'qub, each of them We guided; and before him We guided Nuh, and among his progeny Dawud, Sulayman, Ayyub, Yusuf, Musa and Harun. Thus do We reward the doers of good. And Zakariyya, and Yahya, and 'Isa and Ilyas, each one of them was of the righteous. And Isma'il and Al-Yasa' and Yunus and Lut and each one of them We preferred above the 'Alamin. And also some of their fathers and their progeny and their brethern, We chose them, and We guided them to the straight path.)*([6:83-87](http://legacy.quran.com/6/83-87))
>   Until Allah's statement,
>   *(They are those whom Allah had guided. So follow their guidance.)* ([6:90](http://legacy.quran.com/6/90))
>   Allah, the Exalted, says,
>   *(Of some of them We have related to you their story. And of some We have not related to you their story.)* ([40:78](http://legacy.quran.com/40/78))
>   In [Sahih Al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/urn/44860) it is reported from Mujahid that he asked Ibn 'Abbas, "Is there a prostration in Surah Sad" Ibn 'Abbas replied, "Yes." Then he recited,
>   (*They are those whom Allah had guided. So follow their guidance.*) (6:90) Ibn 'Abbas then said, "So your Prophet is one of those who have been commanded to follow them. And he is of those who should be followed." -- referring to Dawud. Allah, the Exalted, said in this noble Ayah.

So the contradiction lays in your wrong interpretation by interpreting the list as an exclusive list of chosen people.